# Loop through an object and create new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects, I'm trying to loop through them via map function and create an output as follows:

**Desired output**

```
dataSet = [
 [John, Doe, Sales],
 [Jane, Doe, HR], 
 [Jack, Doe, Manager]
]
```

My array of objects:

```
[[object],[object],[object]]
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

```
 users.map((item) => {
  dataSet.push(item.profile.firstName, item.profile.role)
 })
```

However my output:

```
["John","Jane","Jack"]
```

How can I push each loop into new array?

Thanks

Comment: How are you getting that output? What is the actual input? It looks like there should be 6 items in the output array, since you're pushing 2 items per iteration.

Comment: As a sort of aside, if you are not using the return value of `.map()` then you're using `.map()` incorrectly and should be using `.forEach()` instead.

Comment: is your array of objects an array of arrays containing objects? 
`[[{...}],[{...}]]`, or an array of objects `[{...},{...}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, you are pretty close. Just make what you want to push an array. Try the following codes:

```
users.forEach((item) => {
  dataSet.push([item.profile.firstName, item.profile.lastName, item.profile.role]);
});
```

Comment: @4castle you dare absolutely correct. I've updated it

Answer (score 1):

When you are mapping the array of objects you should just return an array with the values you want.

```js
const john = { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', role: 'Sales' }
const jane = { firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe', role: 'HR' }
const jack = { firstName: 'Jack', lastName: 'Doe', role: 'Manager' }
const users = [ john, jane, jack ]
const dataSet = users.map(user => ([ user.firstName, user.lastName, user.role ]))
console.log(dataSet)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your original data looks like:

```
data: [
    ...
    {
        profile: {
            firstname: "John",
            lastname: "Doe",
            role: "Sales"
        }
    },
    ...
];
```

You could do this:

```
var dataSet = data.map((person) => {
    let profile = person.profile;
    return [
        profile.firstname,
        profile.lastname,
        profile.role
    ];
});
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in a more generic way by allowing for any number of properties on the object using *map*, e.g.

```js
dataset = [
           {firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Doe', role: 'Sales'},
           {firstName: 'Jane', lastName: 'Doe', role: 'HR'},
           {firstName: 'Jack', lastName: 'Doe', role: 'Manager'}
          ];

var result = dataset.map(obj => Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]));

console.log(result)
```